# kubectl error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized) 403

Tags: docker, kubernetes

On my local machine i'm running minikube and kubectl. After some testing I removed the local Kubernetes cluster with `minikube remove`. After starting a new cluster kubectl errors out with: `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)` And it won't connected to my cluster anymore.

`kubectl config view` is :

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/luuk/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.99.100:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/luuk/.minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /home/luuk/.minikube/client.key
```

https://192.168.99.100:8443/console returns:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/console\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}
```

any idea what it could be? Remember i'm not using or connected to any third party applications/platforms.

Comment: Are you running minikube and kubectl with the same user? Seems that the problem is the the key from your client config.

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: no i have not been able to solve this problem